# IOS13 AVAudioRecorder is not respecting to set AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey(16)

Tags: ios13, avaudiorecorder

I am using AVAudioRecorder to record voice, and do setting as below:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)recordSetting {
  NSMutableDictionary *recSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  // General Audio Format Settings
  recSetting[AVFormatIDKey] = @(kAudioFormatLinearPCM);
  recSetting[AVSampleRateKey] = @16000;
  recSetting[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = @1;
  // Linear PCM Format Settings
  recSetting[AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey] = @16;
  recSetting[AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey] = @YES;
   recSetting[AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey] = @YES;
  // Encoder Settings
  recSetting[AVEncoderAudioQualityKey] = @(AVAudioQualityMedium);
  recSetting[AVEncoderBitRateKey] = @128000;
  return recSetting;
}
```

It works fine in iOS12, I can record 16bit wav file. After my iOS12 updated to iOS13, I can only record the 32bit file even if I change nothing, still set AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey at 16. So it seems AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey is not effected.

Could any expert support any solution or workaround? I still need 16 bit wav file after recording.

I will be very appreciate any help.

Comment: I saw AVAudioRecord modified from iOS12.4 iOS13.
But don't know what exactly changed. It is most likely the change of AVAudioRecord caused the not respecting result. Anyone know where to check the exactly change.
http://codeworkshop.net/objc-diff/sdkdiffs/ios/13.0/AVFoundation.html

Answer (score 4):

**Quick answer:** You need to set either `AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey` or `AVEncoderBitRateKey`, but not both.

**Explanation:** Bit Depth is only meaningful in reference to a PCM digital signal. Non-PCM formats, such as lossy compression formats, do not have associated bit depths, and use Bit Rate as the number of bits that are conveyed or processed per unit of time, which is commonly used to describe audio stream quality.

According to Apple's [Linear PCM Format Settings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/audio_track_engineering/audio_settings_and_formats/linear_pcm_format_settings), if you want to record uncompressed PCM in a WAV format, you need to set only BitDepth through `AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey` and not BitRate through `AVEncoderBitRateKey`. However, if you wish to use an audio encoder, such as `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` then you can set `AVEncoderBitRateKey` as part of the [Encoder Settings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder/encoder_settings).

Basically, the quality of a PCM stream is represented by two attributes: **Sample Rate** and **Bit Depth**.

The connection between Bit Rate and Bit Depth in PCM digital signal, is given by the following formula:

[image]

**Sample Rate** is the number of samples per time unit, usually per second. A sample is a measurement of signal amplitude and it contains the information of the amplitude value of the signal waveform over a period of time (usually a second), and usually measured in *sample per second* units.

**Bit Depth** is the number of bits of information in each sample, in *bits per sample* units.

**Bit Rate** is the number of bits (data) per unit of time, usually per second. It refers to the audio quality of the stream. It is measured in *bits per second* or Kilobitspersec (kbps), but again, this is less relevant for a PCM stream.

So, as in your example, if you record 16000 samples/second in 16-bit depth and 1 channel, then minimal Bit Rate calculation would be 256,000 bits/second to accommodate the flow of information in a PCM stream, and however not 128000 as in your code.

[image]

Therefore, if you want to record a raw PCM audio as in your code example, you need to set only the BitDepth through `AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey`, without setting BitRate through `AVEncoderBitRateKey`.

More on this topic here: [Understanding Sample Rate, Bit Depth, and Bit Rate](https://www.headphonesty.com/2019/07/sample-rate-bit-depth-bit-rate/), [Bit Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate), [Audio But Depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth) and [Sampling Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing))

Answer (score 1):

You need set AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey to NO.